# How to create multiple textbox in javascript using for loop?

Tags: javascript

I want to add text to dynamically created `textbox`.

```
var dynamicTextBox= "";
    for (var i = 0; i < vm.FitToWork.length; i++) {
        dynamicTextBox+= '<input class="form-control"  name = "DynamicTextBox"  id=  "DynamicTextBox"  type="text" value = "'vm.FitToWork[i]'" />&nbsp;' +
        '<button id="btnAdd"   class="delete-decl">+</button>';

    }
    document.getElementById("TextBoxContainer").innerHTML=dynamicTextBox;
```

its not working..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have syntax error. You are trying to concatenate a variable `vm.FitToWork[i]` but not using concatenation operator (`+`). Try the following code:

```js
var dynamicTextBox= "";

// ignore this. just have this to get the code working
var vm = {FitToWork : ["test","rest","vest"]};

for (var i = 0; i < vm.FitToWork.length; i++) {
      dynamicTextBox += '<input class="form-control"  name = "DynamicTextBox"  id=  "DynamicTextBox"  type="text" value = "' + vm.FitToWork[i] + '" />'; 
      
      dynamicTextBox += '<button id="btnAdd"   class="delete-decl">+</button></br>';
}

document.getElementById("TextBoxContainer").innerHTML = dynamicTextBox;
```

```html
<div id="TextBoxContainer"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You missed concat.

```
var dynamicTextBox= "";
for (var i = 0; i < vm.FitToWork.length; i++) {
    dynamicTextBox+= '<input class="form-control"  name = "DynamicTextBox"  id=  "DynamicTextBox"  type="text" value = "'+vm.FitToWork[i]+'" />&nbsp;' + '<button id="btnAdd"   class="delete-decl">+</button>';
}
document.getElementById("TextBoxContainer").innerHTML=dynamicTextBox;
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add pluses in value:

```
... value="' + vm.FitToWork[i] + '" ...
```

Answer (score 0):

value should be in + +  `value = "' + value + '"`
so `value = "'+vm.FitToWork[i]+'"`

or you can try this

```
 '<input name = "DynamicTextBox" type="text" value = "' + value + '" />' +
 '<input type="button" value="+" id="btnAdd"   class="delete-decl" />'
```